# padding while creating sublists

Tags: python, list

Is there an elegant way how to pad the last sublist with zeroes while creating sublists from a list of integers?

So far I have this oneliner and need to fill the last sublist with 2 zeroes

```py
[lst[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(lst), 3)]
```

for example

```
lst =[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

result should be:

```
[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9][10,0,0]
```

Comment: what is `out`?.

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of inputs and outputs? e.g. for a specific value of `out`, what do you want your code to produce?

Comment: the name of the list, I corrected the question

Comment: I know how to pad the last sublist after the creation, but I am curious if there is a way how to do it simultaneously while creating sublists and if possible as a one-liner

Comment: i think you probably want `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `itertools.zip_longest`, consuming the same iterator created off of the list, and fill in the missing values as 0 :

```
[[*i] for i in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(lst)] * 3, fillvalue=0)]
```

**Example:**

```
In [1219]: lst =[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]                                                                                                                                                            

In [1220]: [[*i] for i in itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(lst)] * 3, fillvalue=0)]                                                                                                                             
Out[1220]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works for python 3 only (which is fine for me), does not it?

Comment: @GrwKřemílek Yes. For Python 2, one can use `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 2):

Without `itertools`:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print([lst[x:x+3]+[0]*(x-len(lst)+3) for x in range(0, len(lst), 3)])
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 0, 0]]
```